# Overlapping Boxplot and Cloudplot with two Y-Axes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like df:

```
df <- structure(list(VarBinariaY = c("1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1"), VarContinuaX = c(0.42125112307258, 0.403089860687032, 
0.501541076926515, 0.285735354525968, 0.838761311257258, 0.728340754751116, 
0.547309613088146, 0.758638551225886, 0.664854867151007, 0.730170585680753
), VarContinuaY = c(0.62294910964556, 0.153794215992093, 0.173481315141544, 
0.441902326885611, 0.556428883690387, 0.300496574025601, 0.778148024342954, 
0.358530796831474, 0.163795455591753, 0.658571016974747)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to plot a boxplot and a cloudplot having in the first Y-axis a character variable (1, 0), and in the second Y-axis a numeric variable between (0,1). I want **both data points/boxplot to overlap with each other, so to be in the same scale**. However, geom_point stays always below the scale of the first Y-axis. Moreover, **I would like to have 2 Y-axis instead of a legend**.

Here is my trial:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = VarContinuaX)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = VarBinariaY ), outlier.shape = NA) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = VarContinuaY, color = as.factor(VarBinariaY ))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"),
                     labels = c("0", "1"),
                     guide = guide_legend(title = "Recommend")) +
  labs(y = "First Axis", color = "Second Axis")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your points are on a continuous Y scale, the easiest way to achieve this is to have your boxplots on the same Y scale. To achieve this, you need only convert the character variable to numeric, since its levels are already 0 and 1. If you leave it as a character variable, ggplot will first convert it to a factor, then use the underlying integer representation of the factor levels as the Y axis positions. However, the integers always start at 1, so the Y axis positions will be 1 and 2, not 0 and 1 as desired.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = VarContinuaX)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = as.numeric(VarBinariaY), group = VarBinariaY),
               outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(y = VarContinuaY, color = VarBinariaY)) +
  scale_y_continuous("First axis", breaks = 0:1,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x, "Second axis")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), guide = "none") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you add some lines to explain the logic?

Comment: @vog done. Hopefully this explains things a bit better.